# Sharepoint 2010 Remove Groups From Add Links dialog for MyLInks Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In Add Link dialog box of MyLinks web part, I need to remove few options from "Existing group" and "Show links to" dropdowns. All options which are being displayed for these fields are out of box. I need to display 'Only Me' option for "Show these links to" field. Similarly I need to show only "General" and "Best Bets" options for "Grouping" field.
Do you know if there is a way to remove unwanted options from these fields?

Here is the screenshot of the dialog box where these drop down fields displayed.

[Add Link Dialog](http://blogs.kma-llc.net/.a/6a0115709993d0970b014e8b5c410e970d-pi)

Comment: This question might be better answered at [the SharePoint SE site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have to write your own web part and just link to that one instead (better method, do this if you really need to do these changes)